# How to fill textarea tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I Tried all the options below

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("about").value="'. $_SESSION['tmpabout'] .'"</script>';
                    echo '<script>document.getElementById("about").innerHTML="'. $_SESSION['tmpabout'] .'"</script>';
                    echo '<script>document.getElementById("about").innerTEXT="'. $_SESSION['tmpabout'] .'"</script>';
```

I am getting filled text in red color, highlight and it is not filling the text area.[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtmFy.png)

Comment: Try using **only** this line `<script>document.getElementById("about").value="'. $_SESSION['tmpabout'] .'"</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Using `document.getElementById("about").innerHTML= [...]` should be working, as shown in the snipped below.

One reason why the textarea content is not being filled might be that the JavaScript is being executed before the HTML textarea is actually being loaded / rendered in the page. To solve this, read about [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

```js
document.getElementById('about').innerHTML = 'test'
```

```html
<textarea id='about'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

innerText should work, not innerTEXT

But also you must take care about $_SESSION['tmpabout'] value: if it has line breaks, it will make you javascript fail. You must deal with that.